# How to use a querySelectorAll in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to trigger [GA events](https://google-analytics.nuxtjs.org/usage/event-tracking) using Nuxt. It's successfully working but it's only returning the first one it runs into because of `document.querySelector` rather than `querySelectorAll`. I have tried the spread operator and a `for()` but still no luck - the compiler just says `cannot read property txt of undefined`.

Here's my v-for:

```html
<ul>
 <li class="li-item" v-for="item in items" :key="item.id" @click="doGA" :data-txt="item.name">
  {{ item.name }}
 </li>
</ul>
```

```html
<ListDetails
   :items="[
     {
       name: 'Lorem',
     },
     {
       name: 'Ipsum',
     },
     {
       name: 'Dolor',
     },
   ]"
/>
```

```js
methods: {
  doGA(){
    this.$ga.event({
       eventCategory: "Ext links",
       eventAction: "click",
       //this.dataset.txt does not work below here either
       eventLabel: document.querySelectorAll('.li-item').dataset.txt;
    });
  }
}
```

So when a user clicks 'Ipsum' it's returning 'Lorem' in GA and likewise for 'Dolor' it will do the same. It is because I have used `document.querySelector` rather than `selectorAll` as I have said above, but I can't get `all()` to work properly.

As we know `querySelector` will return this first one the browser finds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` are usually not the way to go in VueJS, if you want to select something. Either bind with state or find it with a `this.$refs[...]`.

---

With a template looking like this

```html
<ul ref="list">
  <li v-for="item in items" :key="item.id" @click="doGA(item.name)">
    {{ item.name }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

You could call the method on each of your element like this

```js
methods: {
  doGA(itemName){
    this.$ga.event({
       eventCategory: "Ext links",
       eventAction: "click",
       eventLabel: itemName
    })
  }
}
```

---

Otherwise, if you want to send all of them, you can do the following

```html
<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in items" :key="item.id" @click="doGA">
      <span :ref="`item-${item.id}`" :data-txt="`fancyText-${item.id}`">
        number >> {{ item.id }}
      </span>
    </li>
  <ul>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'Lorem',
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Ipsum',
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: 'Dolor',
        },
      ],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async doGA() {
      for (const item of this.items) {
        console.log('element found', this.$refs[`item-${item.id}`][0].dataset.txt)

        await this.$ga.event({
          eventCategory: 'Ext links',
          eventAction: 'click',
          eventLabel: this.$refs[`item-${item.id}`][0].dataset.txt,
        })
      }
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

#### Notes

- [$refs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements) is the way to go in VueJS, rather than `querySelector`.
- `async/await` may be useful if you do care about the order, if you don't and only want to send them, I guess that you can pass on this one.
- You can remove the `span`s, I let it for visibility mainly.
- I used `data` here, but this should behave pretty much the same with any props.