# Custom buttons throwing "Flickity is not defined" in Nuxt application using carousel

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, flickity, vue-flickity

I am trying to wire my own custom buttons to a flickity carousel in a nuxt application. In my carousel component I have this code

```html
<template>
    <ClientOnly>
        <Flickity
            ref="flickity"
            :key="keyIncrementer"
            class="carousel"
            :class="{ 'carousel--active': active }"
            :options="computedOptions"
        >
            <slot />
        </Flickity>
    </ClientOnly>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  beforeCreate() {
      var flkty = new Flickity(".carousel");
      // previous
      var previousButton = document.querySelector('.button--previous')
      previousButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
          flkty.previous()
      })
      // next
      var nextButton = document.querySelector('.button--next')
      nextButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
          flkty.next()
      })
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', this.debounceRefresh)
      nextButton.removeEventListener('click', function () {
          flkty.next()
      })
      previousButton.removeEventListener('click', function () {
          flkty.previous()
      })
  },
}
</script>
```

In my plugins folder I have a vue-flickity.js file

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Flickity from 'vue-flickity'

Vue.component('Flickity', Flickity)
```

Without trying to use my own custom buttons the carousel works fine. But with the custom buttons I get an error message `ReferenceError Flickity is not defined` for this line => `var flkty = new Flickity(".carousel");` and `Missing stack frames`
I am obviously doing something wrong here but what ?

Comment: At this point, it will be faster to provide us a [repro]. Otherwise, I do recommend you to give a read to my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68257167/8816585 Here, you error is happening because you're trying to select something that is not even present in the DOM already. A better approach would be to try this in a `mounted()` hook and with `$refs` as explained in my linked answer.

Comment: As it's shown in the documentation basically: https://github.com/drewjbartlett/vue-flickity#installation-and-usage Also, maybe try to use `const`/`let` rather than the good old `var` too.

Comment: I have read everything and I am now taking a different approach inspired by your answer. I am going to ask a new question rather than editing this one.

Answer (score 1):

Your usage of `Flickity` in `new Flickity()` assumes that the `Flickity` constructor (from the [`flickity` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flickity)) is globally defined (perhaps by `vue-flickity`), but that's not the case. Also, `flickity` and `vue-flickity` are not intended to be used simultaneously like that.

To bind `vue-flickity`'s `next`/`previous` methods as handlers for your own buttons, use `@click` handlers on the buttons that call `this.$refs.flickity.next()`/`this.$refs.flickity.previous()`:

```html
<Flickity ref="flickity" class="carousel">...</Flickity>
<button @click="next">Next</button>
<button @click="prev">Prev</button>
```

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    next() {
      this.$refs.flickity.next()
    },
    prev() {
      this.$refs.flickity.previous()
    },
  },
}
```

This is actually the same example from the [`vue-flickity` usage docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-flickity#installation-and-usage).

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-custom-next-prev-buttons-for-vue-flickity?file=components/CarouselBase.vue)