# How to have a flipbook like turn.js in Nuxt?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vuejs2, nuxt.js

How to can import turn.js to nuxt.js project. When I use through plugin then error Window not define, even though I used it in client mode

- **Update**: I used required package check is client, but I get error **jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3___default(...)(...).turn is not a function**

```html
<template>
    <div id="flipbook">
        <div class="hard">
            Turn.js
        </div>
        <div class="hard" />
        <div> Page 1 </div>
        <div> Page 2 </div>
        <div> Page 3 </div>
        <div> Page 4 </div>
        <div class="hard" />
        <div class="hard" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import $ from 'jquery';

    if (process.client) {
        require('turn.js');
    }

    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log($('#flipbook').turn('page'));
            $('#flipbook'.turn({
                width: 400,
                height: 300,
                autoCenter: true,
            }));
        },

    };
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, what did you tried so far? Can you please share some code? [ask]

Comment: Why jQuery into Nuxt ? Nuxt is Vue.js, doesn't Vue.js satisfy the needs jQuery can solve ?

Comment: @BillalBegueradj it does. It may simply be required by some plugins, like turn.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT + TLDR**: use [flipbook-vue](https://github.com/ts1/flipbook-vue) because it is better on any point really (weight, maintenance, flexibility, doesn't rely on jQuery etc...).
This is also working perfectly fine with Nuxt as [shown here](https://github.com/ts1/flipbook-vue/issues/2#issuecomment-513428916).

---

If you need to install jQuery into your Nuxt project (which I do **not recommend**), you can follow [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68414170/8816585). Still, an alternative without jQuery would be greatly appreciated IMO, even more if you're using it just for selecting an element in the DOM. Is it worth 20kb?

If you want to target a specific element available into your component, please use the [`$refs`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements) syntax, as explained in this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68257167/8816585). And not a usual querySelector.

`require` is node-based, you should rather use `import` since you're in a modern browser based ecosystem when using Vue. Hence, import your package locally with a [dynamic import](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67825061/8816585) is still the best way to go here.

TLDR: something like this is usually enough to make it work

```html
<template>
  <div id="flipbook" ref="flipbook">
    <div class="hard">
      Turn.js
    </div>
    <div class="hard" />
    <div> Page 1 </div>
    <div> Page 2 </div>
    <div> Page 3 </div>
    <div> Page 4 </div>
    <div class="hard" />
    <div class="hard" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  async mounted () {
    if (process.client) {
      const turnJs = await import('turn.js')
      this.$refs.flipbook.turnJs.turn({
        width: 400,
        height: 300,
        autoCenter: true,
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**Meanwhile**, the project did not get any updates for already 10 years so I guess that you can pass on this one.

[image]

Writing your own with a bit of CSS + JS is also totally feasible and will provide the best results IMO.

Comment: I have a question. what is 
```
 this.flipbook.turnJs.turn({
        width: 400,
        height: 300,
        autoCenter: true,
      })
```

Comment: @Stone0409 sorry, as you have guessed, it was missing the `$refs` here.

Comment: I tried, but have error (Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'turn')) :((

Comment: @Stone0409 yeah, I'm not sure of the exact syntax it may be using since it's not a maintained package as written above. The `import` syntax may just not be supported. Do you have something inside of `turnJs`?

Comment: oh yep, nothing is inside turnJs :((((

Comment: @Stone0409 alright, since the [documentation is 404](https://github.com/blasten/turn.js/wiki/Reference), not maintained and since the module only works with `require`, I **HIGHLY** suggest you not using this library. Because loading `jQuery + turnjs` will be around 40kB (if not depending on something else), while Vue is only 23kB. So I do hardly recommend passing on this one and try to find something more modern or do it yourself. Loading 70kB or JS only for a page scroll is a nogo IMO.

Comment: @Stone0409 use this one: https://github.com/ts1/flipbook-vue It is maintained, compatible with Vue, weights 7kB, seems configurable and more pretty IMO.

Comment: i tried, but flipbook don't config inside page :(((

Comment: @Stone0409 where did you tried? Cannot see it.

Comment: @Stone0409 this one seems to be working perfectly fine: https://github.com/ts1/flipbook-vue/issues/2#issuecomment-513428916

Comment: i tried before, but i can't configure the content in each page

Comment: @Stone0409 I'm not sure what you're talking about when saying `in each page`. Nuxt is (at least) an SPA at the end of the day. Could you please give us more details?