# Use flipbook-vue in Nuxt 2 application

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Hello im trying to add [flipbook-vue](https://github.com/ts1/flipbook-vue) to my Nuxt application but im getting weird error that i cant even import it.

Here is reproduction: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-playground-gckgi7?file=plugins%2Fflipbook.js

`import Flipbook from 'flipbook-vue/vue2'` gives this error:

[image]

Comment: Try that one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69874645/8816585 and that one: https://github.com/ts1/flipbook-vue/issues/2#issuecomment-513428916

Comment: @kissu Thank you for your help, above answers didn't work since this package change location of its vue2 version. I added answer how it should be imported.

Answer (score 0):

I have to import it like this to make it work:

`import Flipbook from 'flipbook-vue/dist/vue2/flipbook.mjs`