Nuxt 3 flipbook-vue
I am trying to use flipbook-vue in Nuxt 3 (with tailwindcss) but it's not working.
Help would be appreciated.
I am getting the following warning in the browser console:
Failed to resolve component: Flipbook
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement. 

The component itself is not showing on the page but is in the html:
<flipbook class="flipbook" pages="https://picsum.photos/200/300,https://picsum.photos/200/300,https://picsum.photos/200/300"></flipbook>

plugins/flipbook.client.ts
import FlipBook from "flipbook-vue";

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.component("FlipBook", FlipBook);
});


pages/book.vue
<template>
  <section class="bg-cover">
    <div class="mx-12 my-8 p-4">
      <ClientOnly>
        <Flipbook
          class="flipbook"
          :pages="[
            'https://picsum.photos/200/300',
            'https://picsum.photos/200/300',
            'https://picsum.photos/200/300',
          ]"
        />
      </ClientOnly>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>



Please give a read to that one first: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69874645/8816585 There the syntax as of how to import it into Nuxt properly.

Thank you for replying! I saw your post earlier in the day and tried converting it for Nuxt 3 (I assume it was for Nuxt 2) as I'm using Nuxt 3. Could you possibly provide a working example for Nuxt 3? In Nuxt 3 it says you don't need to register plugins in the config file - https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/plugins

Besides changing nuxtApp.vueApp.component("FlipBook", FlipBook); to nuxtApp.vueApp.component("Flipbook", FlipBook);so that the component injected isFlipbookand notFlipBook` is the only difference I would put here. To show the component you need to apply some CSS, which is not optimal but not game breaker either.

I am not sure how to write it for that plugin, or even if it's a Nuxt or a Flipbook issue.
I achieved to have it locally with this
<script setup>
import Flipbook from 'flipbook-vue'
</script>

<template>
  <Flipbook class="flipbook" :pages="['https://source.unsplash.com/random/400x400?sig=1', 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/400x400?sig=2', 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/400x400?sig=3', 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/400x400?sig=4', 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/400x400?sig=5']" />
</template>

<style scoped>
.flipbook {
  width: auto;
  height: 500px;
}
</style>

That works fine in a component and not having that as a plugin is not too much of a big deal anyway.
Here is a Github comment that I posted, feel free to upvote and follow if you feel really concerned by that issue.
Sorry for not helping further, but I am not working with that kind of stuff a lot lately. I still think that the usual solution is supposed to work well but doesn't in this case.

EDIT: this is a working solution with a Nuxt plugin!
I am currently using 1.0.0-beta.4.
So, this should be your /plugins/flipbook.client.ts
import FlipBook from "flipbook-vue";

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.component("Flipbook", FlipBook);
});

And this is what you could use in a page afterwards
<template>
  <client-only>
    <Flipbook class="flipbook" :pages="['https://source.unsplash.com/random/400x400?sig=1', 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/400x400?sig=2', 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/400x400?sig=3', 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/400x400?sig=4', 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/400x400?sig=5']" />
  </client-only>
</template>

<style scoped>
.flipbook {
  width: auto;
  height: 500px;
}
</style>

Works well and with no errors so far.


Thank you for this! I made a silly mistake. In the plugin I had this
nuxtApp.vueApp.component("FlipBook", FlipBook);
When I was using it, I was using it like this
<Flipbook
Capital "B" vs standard "b"

@Warren this is actually not such a silly mistake because it is such a small detail. But it does indeed not mean the same thing + most people do not pay attention to that part.
