# Accessing one element from an HTMLCollection in a nuxt / vuejs application returns undefined whereas the collection itself is defined

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2, nuxt.js, getelementsbyclassname

I am trying to add a class to an element that I select like this:

```
const element = document.getElementsByClassName('some class names')
```

If I `console.log` this element (`console.log('element?', element`), I get a collection of HTML elements; but if I `console.log` one element (`console.log('element[0]?', element[0])`), it's `undefined`.

Does anyone know why I can't access an element from that collection?

[image]

```
const legendSymbol = document.getElementsByClassName("esri-legend__layer-cell--symbols")
legendSymbol[0].classList.add('hidden')
```

Comment: Why do you need to use `getElementsByClassName` in the first place? In Vue, you could apply it dynamically using some conditional state. Otherwise, the usage of [template $refs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68257167/8816585) is the way to go in a Vue context. Also, please show how you access the collection itself, not just a screenshot.

Comment: Basically I am trying to hide (by adding a class `hidden`) an element in a legend provided by ArcGIS. I am not making this element therefore can't really control it.

Comment: You can still target it by using a `template $ref` AFAIK.

Comment: This is true. I have done it but it seems that I can only reach to a certain level of nesting. I have asked a new question about that here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72375568/in-a-nuxt-application-console-logging-beyond-a-certain-level-of-nesting-returns