# In a nuxt application, console.logging beyond a certain level of nesting returns undefined. How to reach deeply nested elements?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, nuxt.js, console.log, arcgis-js-api

In a nuxtjs application I am trying to access a div in a legend provided by a map from ArcGIS. This div is nested quite deeply in my map element. I gave the map element a ref `map` in order to reach it.

```
<template>
  <div id="viewDiv" ref="map" class="h-full"></div>
</template>
```

This console log

```
console.log(
        'inTheMap?',
        this.$refs.map.children[0].children[2].children[0].children[1]
          .children[0]
      )
```

will return a div but the div that I want to reach is nested deeper. Unfortunately if I console.log just one level deeper (if I add `.children[0]`), the console.log returns `undefined`. My question: is there a limit to how deep we can console.log nested elements ? If yes, is there another way to reach deeply nested elements ?

This is (part of) the code for the map:

```
<template>
  <div id="viewDiv" ref="map" class="h-full"></div>
</template>

<script>
import Map from '@arcgis/core/Map'
import MapView from '@arcgis/core/views/MapView'
import esriConfig from '@arcgis/core/config'
import FeatureLayer from '@arcgis/core/layers/FeatureLayer'
import Legend from '@arcgis/core/widgets/Legend'
import Search from '@arcgis/core/widgets/Search'

export default {
  props: {
    selectedTab: {
      type: Number,
      default: 3,
    },
  },

  data() {
    return {
      project:
        'https://...',
      countries:
        'https://...',
      projectLyr: undefined,
      countryLyr: undefined,
      searchWidget: undefined,
      legend: undefined,
      map: undefined,
      view: undefined,
      fieldName: 'composite_risk',
      renderer: {},
      filter: "dev_type = 'road and railway'",
      impactId: 0,
      hasKmField: true,
      buttonDescription: 'Total Environmental Risk',
      legendSymbol: [],
    }
  },

mounted() {
    esriConfig.apiKey =
      'myToken'

    this.map = new Map({ basemap: 'osm-light-gray' })

    this.view = new MapView({
      map: this.map,
      center: [15, 50],
      zoom: 3,
      container: 'viewDiv',
    })

    this.projectLyr = new FeatureLayer({
      url: this.project,
      outFields: ['*'],
      title: 'Legend',
    })

    this.countryLyr = new FeatureLayer({
      url: this.countries,
      outFields: ['*'],
      title: 'Legend',
    })

    this.view.popup = {
      dockOptions: {
        position: 'bottom-left',
      },
    }

    this.legend = new Legend({
      view: this.view
    })
    this.view.ui.add(this.legend, 'top-right')

  this.updateLayer({
      value: 'composite_risk',
      hasKmField: true,
      title: 'Total Environmental Risk',
    })
},

methods: {
 updateLayer(value) {
      if (typeof value === 'number') {
        this.filter =
          value === 1
            ? "dev_type = 'road' OR dev_type = 'railway'"
            : "dev_type = 'road and railway'"
        value = {
          value: 'composite_risk',
          hasKmField: true,
          title: 'Total Environmental Risk',
        }
        this.view.popup.close()
        this.impactId = 0
      }
      if (!value.isFilter) {
        this.fieldName = value.value
        this.hasKmField = value.hasKmField
        this.buttonDescription = value.title
      } else {
        this.filter = `${value.value}`
      }
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        if (this.selectedTab === 0) {
          this.map.remove(this.projectLyr)
          this.map.add(this.countryLyr)
          this.filtering(value)
        } else {
          this.map.remove(this.countryLyr)
          this.map.add(this.projectLyr)
          this.filtering(value)
        }
        this.layer.popupTemplate =
          this.selectedTab === 0
            ? this.popupTemplateCountry
            : this.popupTemplateProject
      })
      console.log(
        'inTheMap?',
     this.$refs.map.children[0].children[2].children[0].children[1]
          .children[0]
      )
    },
}
```

[image]

This is the div I would like to hide:
[image]

Comment: I do not think there is a limit. If it gives you `undefined`, that is the value, no other reason. I am pretty sure there must be another way of reaching an element. Are you creating the map, the legend?, what is the target inside the legend?

Comment: There is not limit regarding those DOM selectors. Try to use your browser devtools to debug those faster.

Comment: @cabesuon I am creating a map, a view and a legend. In the view I add the map and the legend. Inside the legend I am trying to target a div to which I want to add a class (to hide  it).

Comment: @kissu I have used the devtools and I can see the div that I want to target. But I can't access it.

Comment: Do you have a codesandbox?

Comment: Can you show in an image what you are trying to hide?

Comment: @kissu I am trying to set up and codesandbox but it's not working very well right now.

Comment: @cabesuon I have updated my question, you can see the div I want to hide

Comment: You can also provide a Github repo if it's not working great.

Answer (score 0):

In order to reach the element you can start on the `container` node of the legend.

This is a step by step code sample in order to get to the desire element. There is no exist checks in order to simplify.

```
// first get all service entries of the legend container
const legend_services = legend.container.querySelectorAll(".esri-legend__service");
// this will have the same order as they have in the map
// in this case we want the fist legend service
const desire_legend_service = legend_services[0];
// now you want the legend layer entry in the legend service
const legend_layer = desire_legend_service.querySelector(".esri-legend__layer");
// now in your case you want to hide the first table of the legend layer
const legend_layer_first_table = legend_layer.querySelector(".esri-legend__layer-table");
legend_layer_first_table.classList = "hide";
```

`hide` class is just,

```
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

Now, one thing in order for this to work is that the `legend` needs to be display on screen. You need an strategy to secure this before searching for the `div` element to hide.