# How to use a querySelector in Nuxt 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to initialise `IntersectionObserver` in each page of my website built with [Nuxt3](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/).

Therefore, I want to access each HTML element that has a specific CSS class. However, on page change, I noticed that via `onMounted` hook the detected elements are from the previous page.

Here a easy to reproduce example:

`app.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <NuxtPage />
  </div>
</template>
```

`pages/index.vue`

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
onMounted(() => {
  console.group("index.vue");
  console.log(document.querySelector("#container"));
  console.groupEnd();
});
</script>

<template>
  <div id="container">
    <h1>INDEX</h1>
    <NuxtLink to="/work">
      Go to work
    </NuxtLink>
  </div>
</template>
```

`pages/work.vue`

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
onMounted(() => {
  console.group("work.vue");
  console.log(document.querySelector("#container"));
  console.groupEnd();
});
</script>

<template>
  <div id="container">
    <h1>WORK</h1>
    <NuxtLink to="/">
      Go to index
    </NuxtLink>
  </div>
</template>
```

Simply, the result in the console always come from the previous DOM. Here the steps:

- Load the page on `index.vue`, you see the right element in the console.
- Go to `work.vue` using the link.
- See the console showing the exact same result as previously, yet with an added empty class attribute on `#container`

My question is, why does `onMounted` hook doesn't show the right DOM on page change?

I tried to set the page transition to the default mode:

```js
definePageMeta({
  pageTransition: {
    mode: 'default',
  },
});
```

Nothing changed.

> **NOTE**: I am using nuxt version: `3.0.0-rc.9`

Comment: Mainly because you're not supposed to use any kind of querySelector but rather rely on state (Vue is a state based framework). So, I recommend you targeting those same elements but with a template ref rather.

Comment: Yeah, but I think this behaviour is not obvious. It seems strange. My problem is solved using refs. Instead of using `document` I give a ref to a container and then use `querySelector` on it. Works perfectly fine. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of usage, you should use template refs: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#accessing-the-refs

Otherwise, Vue will not behave as expected. More details can be found in this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68257167/8816585).